# What other similar sites exist?

Tags: discussion

In terms of deciding how we should manage this community, we should consider if there are any other similar communities out there and how they manage themselves. So are there any other communities that exist online either solely for the purpose of recommending software or as one of its major functions?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Unfinished answer, have to run out the door...community wiki'ing this so others can edit. The goal of this answer is to provide a meaningful overview of the most major players and the way they relate to what we do here.

---

Yes, other sites exist for the purpose of connecting people with useful software.

#### Similarity / Popularity

- [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/) offers a cross referenced database of what software is roughly equivalent to sorted by popularity.
- [SimilarSites](http://www.similarsites.com/) is similar to (couldn't resist) Alternative To except for an extreme focus on web based apps (and non apps).

See also [alternatives to alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/software/alternativeto/?platform=online).

#### Feature comparison / Matrix

#### Directories

Lots of sites try so sort and categorize all or a subset of available software in a way that people can find something that does what they want.

- [FindTheBest](http://www.findthebest.com/category/Software) has a software directory.
- [i use this](http://iusethis.com) (lack of capitalization theirs) is a directory sorted by popularity with tags to help you find stuff.
- [Software Informer](http://software.informer.com/) (besides being spyware?) is a software directory with search and reviews and suggestions based on what other people like you are using.
- [CNET Download](http://download.cnet.com/) is a very commercialized and successful venture in this space, combining a directory with actual downloads, lots of advertising, and software reviews to keep you hooked.
- Various FOSS directories like [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) and [Open Source Software Directory](http://www.opensourcesoftwaredirectory.com/) as well as repositories like GitHub, Sourceforge, and Launchpad also play in this space. They are communities that help people find relevant software with varying degrees of effectiveness.

#### Customized solution recommendations

This field (the one we are in) has fewer players.

Comment: Excellent answer!